# CarrierWave + RMagick Square Crop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, carrierwave, rmagick

I am trying to make a fixed square image crop with Ruby on Rails, CarrierWave, and RMagick.

I have tried both of the following with no luck...

```
version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fit => [200, 200]
end
```

and

```
version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
end
```

resize_to_limit obviously resizes the image to fit within the specified dimensions while retaining the original aspect ratio. So that's not right, but resize_to_fit doesn't do it either. I am looking at all of the available of the instance methods [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/0.5.1/CarrierWave/RMagick).

I want to be able to upload a picture of any aspect ratio and dimensions and it will come out at 200x200.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally got this! After trying a bunch of different custom image manipulation functions and manual cropping it's actually as simple as I had hoped for...

```
process :resize_to_fill => [400, 400]
```

Crops it into a 400x400 square from the direct center of the original image.

Comment: Be sure to add/uncomment the `include CarrierWave::RMagick` in your uploader for this to work.

Comment: Plus here are the docs http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/0.5.1/CarrierWave/RMagick#resize_to_fill-instance_method “Resize the image to fit within the specified dimensions while retaining the aspect ratio of the original image. *If necessary, crop the image in the larger dimension.*”

Answer (score 1):

[gbdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764500/gbdev), your answer is absolutely correct. But watch out! You must stop/restart your rails server if you're changing the process argument.

E.g. if you currently have:

```
process :resize_to_fit => [400, 400]
```

and you want to change to:

```
process :resize_to_fill => [400, 400]
```

then you have to bounce your server to see the changes take effect.

Note that this only applies to the **key** of that argument hash, and not the *value*. So if you're simply just changing the dimensions e.g. from 800x800 to 400x400, then there's no need to bounce the server.